# Obter Valores de Radio e Text em Ordem

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Boa note.

Estou com um problema na logica de como proceder entre um conjunto de perguntas e respostas.Tenho o codigo abaixo formado por inputs com os tipos text e radio.Quero recuperar as informações destes elementos na ordem que eles se APRESENTAM.Os inputs se apresentam na sequencia pergunta e resposta.Quando o usuário terminar de fazer as perguntas e as resposta quero que as informações sejam alocadas em um vetor onde as perguntas ficaram em indece impar e as resposta em indece par(Considerando 1 como primeiro indece do vetor) E CONSIDERANDO A SEQUENCIA DO DOCUMENTO OU SEJA OS DADOS DA PRIMEIRA PERGUNTA FICAM NO INDECE 1 OS DADOS DA RESPOSTA DA PERGUNTA 1 FICAM NO INDECE 2 .OS DADOS DA PERGUNTA 2 FICA NO INDECE 2 E SUA RESPOSTA FICA NO INDECE 3.(Valores dos rádios selecionados)

```
<input type="text" class="pergunta">

<div><input type="radio" class="resposta" name="grupo1"  
value="num1">numero 1</div>
<div><input type="radio" class="resposta" name="grupo1" 
value="num2">nunero 2</div>
<div><input type="radio" class="resposta" name="grupo1" 
value="num3">numero 3</div>

<input type="text" class="pergunta">

<input type="text" class="resposta">

<input type="text" class="pergunta">

<div><input type="radio" class="resposta" name="grupo2"  
value="num1">numero 1</div>
<div><input type="radio" class="resposta" name="grupo2" 
value="num2">nunero 2</div>
<div><input type="radio" class="resposta" name="grupo2" 
value="num3">numero 3</div>

<input type="button" value='botao'id="botao">
```

Estou usando o a função each para pegar os dados só que ela pega os dados de um tipo primeiro ex text e depois pega os radio

Comment: 'Os dados da resposta da pergunta 1 fica no índice 2 e os dados da pergunta 2 fica no índice 2', como assim? consegue explicar oque deseja de uma forma objetiva e clara?

Comment: E por que que a sua pergunta fica em um input, sendo que provavelmente é um valor de saída e não de entrada?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você utilizar o selector do JQuery, ele já obtém os elementos para você na ordem em que eles se encontram no HTML.

Nesse caso específico, você poderia fazer o seguinte:

```
$("input[type='text'], input[name='grupo1']:checked, input[name='grupo2']:checked")
```

Esse selector iria obter todos os campos para você na ordem mesma que você mencionou que queria (já que essa ordem coincide com a ordem organizada no código HTML que você passou). Depois disso, basta você fazer um `.each()` para percorrer os elementos e obter todos os valores.

**Código completo:**

```js
$('#botao').click(function(){
  var lista = [];
 $("input[type='text'], input[name='grupo1']:checked, input[name='grupo2']:checked").each(function(i, el){
  lista.push($(el).val());
  });
  console.log(lista);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Pergunta 1:
<input type="text" class="pergunta">
<br>
Resposta 1:
<div><input type="radio" class="resposta" name="grupo1"  
value="num1">numero 1</div>
<div><input type="radio" class="resposta" name="grupo1" 
value="num2">nunero 2</div>
<div><input type="radio" class="resposta" name="grupo1" 
value="num3">numero 3</div>
<br>
Pergunta 2:
<input type="text" class="pergunta">
<br>
Resposta 2:
<input type="text" class="resposta">
<br>
Pergunta 3:
<input type="text" class="pergunta">
<br>
Resposta 3:
<div><input type="radio" class="resposta" name="grupo2"  
value="num1">numero 1</div>
<div><input type="radio" class="resposta" name="grupo2" 
value="num2">nunero 2</div>
<div><input type="radio" class="resposta" name="grupo2" 
value="num3">numero 3</div>
<br>
<input type="button" value="botao" id="botao">
```

Answer (score 1):

Crie antes uma array com 1 elemento inicial vazio, que será o índice `0` para que os outros comecem a partir do 1. Após isso é ir fazendo loop nas perguntas e adicionando à array os resultados:

```js
var resultado = [''];
$("#botao").click(function(){
   var perguntas = $(".pergunta");
   for(var x=0; x<perguntas.length; x++){
      resultado.push($(perguntas[x]).val());
      if( $(perguntas[x]).next().hasClass("resposta") ){
         resultado.push($(perguntas[x]).next().val());
      }else{
         var radios = $(perguntas[x]).next().children("input[type='radio']").attr("name");
         var checado = $("input[name='"+radios+"']:checked").val();
         resultado.push(checado);
      }
   }
   console.log(resultado);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Pergunta 1:
<br />
<input type="text" class="pergunta">
<div>
   <input type="radio" class="resposta" name="grupo1" value="num1">numero 1
</div>
<div>
   <input type="radio" class="resposta" name="grupo1" value="num2">nunero 2
</div>
<div>
   <input type="radio" class="resposta" name="grupo1" value="num3">numero 3
</div>
<br />
Pergunta 2:
<br />
<input type="text" class="pergunta">
Resposta 2:
<input type="text" class="resposta">
<br /><br />
Pergunta 3:
<br />
<input type="text" class="pergunta">
<div>
   <input type="radio" class="resposta" name="grupo2" value="num1">numero 1
</div>
<div>
   <input type="radio" class="resposta" name="grupo2" value="num2">nunero 2
</div>
<div>
   <input type="radio" class="resposta" name="grupo2" value="num3">numero 3
</div>
<input type="button" value='botao'id="botao">
```